# Discord.py unmute error: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have been writing my unmute function for my discord.py bot. Once i was finished, i tried to run it, and this error popped up:
'coroutine' object is not callable

This is my code btw:

```
@bot.command(description="Unmutes a specified user.")
@commands(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
   mutedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

   await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
   await member.send(f" you have unmutedd from: - {ctx.guild.name}")
   embed = discord.Embed(title="unmute", description=f" unmuted-{member.mention}",colour=discord.Colour.green())
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

What shall i do?

Comment: please include the whole error message. Which line produces it?

Comment: You can't put Python into the code snippet  it's only for html/css/javascript

Comment: well, i can, soo

Answer (score 2):

The decorator `@commands(manage_messages=True)` does not exist.

I assume you meant `@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)`. That should work

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has%20permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions

Comment: It still says something like: 'Command' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'.

Comment: My import is: from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

Comment: just import `from discord.ext import commands`, thats enough

Comment: Fixed it! I was using 'commands' as a name for another command, which was apparently messing up my other code.